# Using custom fileformat to read xml files in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm new to Hadoop/Hive. I am trying to process xml files  with hive.After googling for a while ,I came across custom FileFormat code for xml files that can be used for the purpose .

(Here is the source code for custom xmlinputformat class :    [XmlInputFormat.class](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/ad84344e4055b1e6adff5779339a33fa29e1265d/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/classifier/bayes/XmlInputFormat.java)

I  added the jar for xmlinputformat class and created a sample table as :

```
create table person ( 
    name string
    )        
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'    
    STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.hadoop.xmlparser.XmlInputFormat'
    OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat';
```

I've tried to retrieve data from the above table and got the following error :

**Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask**

Following are the errors found in the jobtracker logs :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.Hadoop20SShims$CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(Hadoop20SShims.java:306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.Hadoop20SShims$CombineFileRecordReader.<init>(Hadoop20SShims.java:269)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.Hadoop20SShims$CombineFileInputFormatShim.getRecordReader(Hadoop20SShims.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:264)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun
```

Any solutions for the above problem ?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this particular InputFormat but Hive assumes that records are delimited by \n. So you would need to make sure that your XML has no \n.